# No code executing after Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that `INSERT`s a user into a database using a prepared Mysql statement. There are no errors thrown, but for some reason any code after the execution of the statement doesn't run. Any code before it will run. Everything looks fine, and I have no clue what could be causing this. Code is as follows:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `testDb`
            (`email`, `id`, `created_at`, `password`, `access_token`)
        VALUES
            (:email, :id, :currentDate, :password, :token)";

$stmt = $DBH->prepare($SQL);

$insertArray = array(
    ":email"        =>  "some Email",
    ":currentDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ":id"   =>  "some id",
    ":password" =>  "some pass",
    ":token"        =>  $access_token
);
$stmt->execute($insertArray);
// All of this following code doesn't execute,
// including all the other following code after all this code
$responseData = array(
    "user_id"       =>  $DBH->lastInsertId(),
    "access_token"  =>  $access_token,
    "new_user"      =>  1
);
print_r($responseData);
echo 'TESTTTTTT';
```

What I mean when no code is execute is that nothing get's printed out, or any of the functions that were below this code that weren't listen get executed either. But when the `$stmt->execute($insertArray);` gets commented out, everything else below gets executed.

Edit: 
Error attributes were set in the beginning of the file and everything was already wrapped in a try/ catch. Here is what was set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('log_errors','1');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Tried all the recommendations, but nothing worked, no errors were thrown. The only thing that worked was commenting out these two lines:

```
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

After that was commented out, the rest of the code executes, but it seems like it can't get any data from the db now, Ex. all fetch arrays come up empty even though they shouldn't be.

Comment: `$didItWorkOrNot = $stmt->execute($insertArray); echo $didItWorkOrNot;`  Execute returns a boolean. That might be helpful.

Comment: Are you using PDO? Are PDO Exceptions active? Did you configure your php server to hide errors to the user? Check your error log file.

Comment: Already tried something like that, put it in an "if" statement but nothing at all was echo'd out. Just tried what you said too but nothing showed up, just blank

Comment: Still haven't solved it, got it to somewhat work by commenting out the 

$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing these two lines above all code

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before, put this before any of your code to get PDO to throw exceptions:

```
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then wrap the code in question with a `try...catch` block so you can pinpoint what exactly is happening.